# Google Maps: Border on Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display photos as markers on Google Maps. This is no problem by redefining the marker as an image, but I want to put some sort of border or shadow to make them stand out better. Something like the Google photos would be best, but I guess this is too complicated, if at all possible. A simple 1px solid border would do fine. One option is to actually change the image, but this is not an option. Also, the images are different sizes so I can not put a black image as the shadow (1px larger than the original).

Here is the idea:

CURRENT:

[image]

LOOKING FOR:

[image]

EVEN COOLER:

[image]

IDEAL WORLD:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the Rich Marker v3 library [demo](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/examples/richmarker.html) (*the [actual library](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker)*) which allows to use custom html as a marker.

Setting a marker html of

```
<img 
  src="http://www.picturesofengland.com/img/S/1015720.jpg" 
  style="border:2px solid white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;" 
/>
```

and clicking the toggle flat (*an option in the library api*) would do what you want.. *you alter the image src of course ;)*

for more libraries look at http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Comment: tried it but couldn't manage to set a animation like "BOUNCE" on it. Anyone managed to do this ?

Comment: The links are dead

Comment: @kaiser thanks for the heads up. All google map utilities have been moved to github. Updated links.

Answer (score 1):

@Cinetik's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011807/google-maps-border-on-markers/6012058#comment-22695588) led me to overcome a conceptual barrier. I, too, was trying to use [RichMarkers](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html) in my app, and I too was trying to animate them. When I discovered that RichMarker's `setAnimation` doesn't just work, I too was furious. Then I made that comment above,

> "I'd like to have my rich marker and animate it too"

and realized my misconception. I am sharing my answer for posterity:

> Google map's [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Marker) has all kinds of crazy features, like
>   out-of-the-box animations. It doesn't allow for HTML/CSS/JS
>   manipulation, though, because it doesn't produce clean HTML markers.
>   If you want that, you need RichMarker. The problem is, you can't have
>   you cake and eat it too. If you opt-in to RichMarker's elegant
>   HTML/CSS/JS integration, you automatically opt-out of some of the
>   nicer features of the plain Marker. You can implement them yourself,
>   if you want, and having that freedom is exactly why you chose
>   RichMarker in the first place, isn't it?
>
> So, here is some code to add a bounce animation to a RichMarker using jQuery and the amazing '[bez](https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez)' plugin by rdallasgray.

```
// create a marker using our element
var marker = new RichMarker({
    content: $("myElement").get(0)
});

// now animate that element!
$("#myElement").animate({ left: -100 }, 500, $.bez([0,0,0.6,1]));
```

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

You want to use im (ImageMagick) to automatically create a border for the image.

Comment: Do you have a bit more details? I can not find "im" details...? http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to do this without manipulating the images themselves. I aim to do this by using CSS/styling, if possible.

Comment: No problem, did you checked Gaby's post? Isn't it a correct answer?