# Marker styling in Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Is it possible to do something like this [marker styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011807/google-maps-border-on-markers) using Gmaps4rails gem. I`ve managed to get by with [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries), but it was written in the [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers)

How could I add some border for a custom marker picture? or add some css to it? to all my marker pictures? I found it ugly doing this with shadow picture.

Comment: looks like a good feature to add, keep in touch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just added this to the gem. Available on github now (doc updated as well, same link as marker styling).

Will be included in `0.11.1`

In short:

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
  {
  "rich_marker" => "<div class='my-marker'>It works!<img height='30' width='30' src='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3212/3012579547_097e27ced9_m.jpg'/></div>"
  }
end
```

With the proper css:

```
.my-marker {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  font: 10% "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: @mu is too short: indeed SO is a great source of precious feedback

Comment: I mean when i`m making my Markers like this `@markers = '[ {"description": "", "title": "", "sidebar": "", "lng": "", "lat": "", "picture": "", "width": "", "height": ""} ]` is it possible to add `"rich_marker":"<h1>!</h1>"`??? Thanks prior 8)

Comment: :D what an enthusiast! Once again, consider upvoting some of my answers, that's my only salary for the gem :)